# Watch Changes in Vue Observable

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement a method to check a users login status based on firebase's `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()`. I would like to use this across my app as a global variable.

At the moment, I am using a `Vue.observable` store to set the value of my signed in state.

`store.js`

```js
export const store = Vue.observable({
  signedIn: false,
});

export const mutations = {
  setSignedIn(bool) {
    store.signedIn = bool;
  },
};
```

At the start of my app, I then call the check auth function
`App.vue`

```js
   import {mutations} from './store'
   this.$firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        mutations.setSignedIn(true);
      } else {
        mutations.setSignedIn(false);
      }
    });
```

Finally, within one of my child components I check the store to see the signedIn status. Based on that, I will either use the `chrome.storage` if not signed in, or `firebase` if signed in.

`List.js`

```js
     import {store} from './store'
      if (store.signedIn) {
        // use firebase
      } else {
       // use chrome storage
      }
```

My main issue is that the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` function is `asynchronous` thus my `store.signedIn` value is always false and it does not update when it changes.

My goal is to wait until the `onAuthStateChanged` is done and check the `store.signedIn` but my attempts have not worked so far.

Comment: where do you run `this.$firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged...` exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a computed property called `isSignedIn` then watch it using `watch` option :

```
import {store} from './store'

export default{

 ...
computed:{
   isSignedIn(){
         return store.signedIn;
        }
},
watch:{
   isSignedIn(newVal,oldVal){
    if (newVal) {
        // use firebase
      } else {
       // use chrome storage
      }
 }
}
}
```